# Adding Wi-Fi to a TCP/IP application that is already running with Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, wifi, tcp-ip

What to do if you have an Ethernet application that is already up and running with TCP/IP functionality and now you want to add Wi-Fi. Most of the Wi-Fi modules available have embedded TCP/IP stacks with some kind of api interface you have to use (i.e. TCP_open(google.com, 80)). This is good if you are starting a fresh application and want to be able to quickly get something simple up and running.

But what if you already have a complex application with TCP/IP stack and you just want it to use Wi-Fi? You want to be able to take the raw Ethernet packets that are coming out of your TCP/IP stack and send them to the Wi-Fi module. I have found a few Wi-Fi modules that allow this "TCP/IP bypass" feature but not many.

To me it doesn't seem like that unique of an application and I wonder why it is not easier to find modules that allow this type of solution.
What are others doing in this situation? i.e. - an existing TCP application where you'd like to "drop in" Wi-Fi

Comment: You want a "bridge". Random example: http://www.silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/embedded-wireless/serial-ethernet-wifi-modules/sx-680/

Comment: Then you want a real embedded operating system with a real TCP/IP stack, not one in which stacks are bolted into apps or walled-garden components.

Comment: The bridge device looks nice. That would serve the purpose except that I want to integrate the solution. And end up with a device that has an Ethernet interface and a Wi-Fi interface.

Comment: Did you able to come up with a solution? I am also searching for the solution.

Comment: Did you able to come up with a solution? I am also searching for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The modules that have the embedded TCP/IP stack all have a Cortex M3, M4 or similar processor to run the stack. You need a module without the processor, so you can use the stack on your existing processor. They are available, I'm using a Murata SN8000, partly because the drivers for Freescales Linux are available. These processor-less modules are cheaper and have better performance than the embedded processor versions.

Comment: So does it have a simple API? for example: scan_networks() //return list of wifi networks in the area; set_mac_address() //to set the mac address the module will use; send_raw_data() //send Ethernet packet; that kind of stuff?